# Google Charts from JSON file error - table has no columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am working on the Google Charts tutorial at [this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example)

I have changed the jQuery CDN to the following:

```
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

All three files (JSON, HTML, PHP) are in the same directory. No code has been changed than what is on the page above.

When I run the HTML page, I get the error:

`Table has no columns`

What do I need to change?

Comment: I removed the double quotes from keys, as is described in the format, but it still hasn't worked :/

Comment: @WhiteHat it is on the link in the question above: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Comment: are you using the exact same `$.ajax` properties, with `async: false`?